# SI4T: Commit failed after getSolrServer

Tags: 2011, si4t

This is part two of an SI4T installation troubleshoot using Tridion 2011 and SOLR 4.8. [Part one has been seemingly resolved](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8431/si4t-configuration-no-data-access-object-factory) with the correct combination of JAR files from each of the SI4T Github repositories.

Last night I was able to start the deployer, publish a page, and witness the logs reference actually making its way through the SI4T SOLR storage extension. Sadly, at the split second prior to a successful publish it failed with a very unhelpful message in Tridion. Luckily, the logs on the deployer seemed a bit more helpful:

```
[11/25/14 16:41:02:642 CST] 0000005d SolrIndexer   I org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer removeItemFromIndex Adding removeItemFromIndex: [REMOVE,dcp:84-45296-13488,COMPONENT_PRESENTATION,abcdeployerdb]
[11/25/14 16:41:02:646 CST] 0000005d SolrIndexer   I org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer setSolrUrl Using [http://aixpcibld01:9191/solr/collection1] to connect to.
[11/25/14 16:41:02:649 CST] 0000005d SolrIndexDisp I org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexDispatcher getSolrServer Obtaining Http Solr server [http://aixpcibld01:9191/solr/collection1: http://aixpcibld01:9191/solr/collection1
[11/25/14 16:41:02:657 CST] 0000005d SolrIndexer   I org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer commit Clearing out registers.
[11/25/14 16:41:02:660 CST] 0000005d StorageManage I com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory commitTransaction Commit failed
[11/25/14 16:41:02:696 CST] 0000005d CommitPhase   W com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase handleFailure Failed to commit: tcm:0-260756-66560 error: Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560
[11/25/14 16:41:02:699 CST] 0000005d StorageManage I com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory rollbackTransaction Rolling back storage transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560
[11/25/14 16:41:02:702 CST] 0000005d StorageManage I com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory rollbackTransaction Transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560 was no longer or active or already rolled back
[11/25/14 16:41:02:704 CST] 0000005d DeployPipelin W com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor runMainExecutePhase Phase: Deployment Commit Phase failure message: Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560, Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560, Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560 for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560
[11/25/14 16:41:02:708 CST] 0000005d DeployPipelin E com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor runMainExecutePhase Final attempt in Phase: Deployment Commit Phase failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560
[11/25/14 16:41:02:712 CST] 0000005d DeployPipelin E com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor runMainExecutePhase Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560
                             com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560, Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560, Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.handleFailure(CommitPhase.java:100)
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.execute(CommitPhase.java:84)
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:185)
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:96)
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:60)
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:81)
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:450)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:929)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Embedded exception:
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.AbstractStorageStep.commitTransaction(AbstractStorageStep.java:34)
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.execute(CommitPhase.java:74)
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:185)
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:96)
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:60)
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:81)
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:450)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:929)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Embedded exception:
com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.commitTransaction(StorageManagerFactory.java:357)
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.AbstractStorageStep.commitTransaction(AbstractStorageStep.java:32)
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.execute(CommitPhase.java:74)
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:185)
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:96)
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:60)
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:81)
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:450)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:929)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

[11/25/14 16:41:02:717 CST] 0000005d TransactionPe I com.tridion.deployer.model.transaction.TransactionPersistence remove Removing deployment transaction information: tcm:0-260756-66560
[11/25/14 16:41:02:810 CST] 0000005d DeployPipelin E com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor handlePipelineError Unable to start processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-260756-66560
[11/25/14 16:41:02:831 CST] 0000005d DeployPipelin I com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor execute Transaction is completed: tcm:0-260756-66560
[11/25/14 16:41:02:842 CST] 0000005d DeployPipelin I com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor execute Finished executing deployment pipeline for: tcm:0-260756-66560 in 33776 ms.
[11/25/14 16:41:02:844 CST] 0000005d TransactionMa I com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager cleanup Cleaning up Deployment package for transaction: tcm:0-260756-66560 and type: CONTENT
[11/25/14 16:41:03:005 CST] 0000005d TransactionMa I com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager handleDeployPackage Finished handling of Deployment package: tcm:0-260756-66560 with type: CONTENT
[11/25/14 16:41:05:062 CST] 00000051 HTTPSReceiver I com.tridion.transport.HTTPSReceiverServlet handleNotification Removed file at /apps01/tridion/incoming_rel/tcm_0-260756-66560.state.xml
```

I'm currently setting up a local dev environment to have a go with debugging, but the access to infrastructure may not allow it. I'm hoping someone might chime in heroically with an AHA! response. [My original question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8431/si4t-configuration-no-data-access-object-factory) contains a link to my storage config.

Comment: Hi Again. Can you post your logback config? If you've used the config as is on Github @ Si4t, then you should also have an extension log. This will show the more exact error. If you're using websphere, the actual error may also appear in application.log.

Answer (score 4):

When you see these messages:

```
[11/25/14 16:41:02:649 CST] 0000005d SolrIndexDisp I org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexDispatcher getSolrServer Obtaining Http Solr server [http://aixpcibld01:9191/solr/collection1: http://aixpcibld01:9191/solr/collection1
[11/25/14 16:41:02:657 CST] 0000005d SolrIndexer   I org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer commit Clearing out registers.
```

In this order, it means that the si4t indexer was not able to obtain a connection to the actual Solr server. This can be anything, from firewalls to mismatched versions, to the wrong dependencies.

First, verify that you are able to connect to the machine at all on port 9191. Then check your stdout or stderr log for any exception - it should be logged.

Since this specific error occurs at the moment an http client is created, it may simply be that you're missing httpclient-*.jar in your classpath.